# É possível chamar uma função PHP através do AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

Na minha pagina PHP eu tenho as funções: cadastro(), editar() e remover().
Como posso fazer para que, quando o ajax enviar os dados em "index.php" caia na funçao "cadastro()"?

AJAX:

```
$('form[name="cad-form"]').submit(function(){
  var dados = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url: '**cadastro.php**',
      type: 'post',
      data: dados,
      success:function(data){
        if (data == "sucesso") {
          alert("Cliente cadastrado com sucesso! :)");
        } else {
          alert("Não foi possível realizar o cadastro :( verifique todos os campos ou contate o suporte técnico.")
        }
      }
    })
  return false;
})
```

PHP:

```
<?php
/* CADASTRO DE CLIENTE */
function Cadastro() {
  $nome     = $_POST['nome'];
  $dataNasc = explode('/', $_POST['data_nasc']);
  $dataNasc = $dataNasc[2].'-'.$dataNasc[1].'-'.$dataNasc[0];
  $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
  $endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
  $cpf      = $_POST['cpf'];
  $rg       = $_POST['rg'];

   $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=luanaconsolini', 'root', '');

    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cliente SET
      nome = :nome,
      dataNascimento = :data,
      telefone = :tel,
      endereco = :endereco,
      cpf = :cpf,
      rg = :rg");
    $sql->bindValue(':nome', $nome);
    $sql->bindValue(':data', $dataNasc);
    $sql->bindValue(':tel', $telefone);
    $sql->bindValue(':endereco', $endereco);
    $sql->bindValue(':cpf', $cpf);
    $sql->bindValue(':rg', $rg);
    $sql->execute();
    if($sql->rowCount()>0){
      echo "sucesso";
    }else{
      echo "erro";
    }
}
```

Obrigado desde já :)

Comment: WesLipe, dá pra colocar as outras funções no seu PHP, você diz que tem cadastro(), editar() e remover(). mas só estou vendo a cadastro(). No seu HTML tem opções para cadastrar, editar ou remover? Tem que mostrar o código de acordo com a pergunta

Comment: Não adianta que caia na funçao "cadastro()" porque tem vários detalhes que devem ser corrigido para que funcione corretamente

Comment: Leo, boa tarde. eu coloquei so a funçao cadastro pra nao muito longo, mas basicamente eu tenho essas 3 funçoes: cadastro, editar e remover, e o ajax envia os dados do form pra pagina "cadastro.php"

Comment: Certo, mas como o PHP vai saber se está enviando pra cadastrar, editar ou deletar? o que tem no formulario pra indicar a função que tem que executar?

Comment: É essa a minha duvida kk a principio, eu começava o meu codigo php ja chamando a funçao "cadastro()", mas acredito que exista maneiras muito melhores de se fazer isso, so nao sei como

Comment: vou colocar uma resposta bem basica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa fazer com que o PHP entenda que está recebendo uma requisição e ele mesmo invoque o método desejado. Existem **diversas** formas de fazer isso, vou dar um exemplo bem simples, mas recomendo que dê uma olhada em alguns projetos já existentes, ou tutoriais como este [aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-um-cadastro-com-php-ajax-e-jquery/28046) e [este outro](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp).

```
if (!empty($_POST)){ // caso $_POST não esteja vazio, chame Cadastro()
  Cadastro();
}
```

É interessante também que você valide algumas coisas, como por exemplo a existência dos índices que irá utilizar (data_nasc, telefone, etc) pois caso o usuário envie apenas o nome, por exemplo, mas o restante não, sua função irá falhar.

Comment: Isso não resolve o problema.

Comment: Não existe um "problema" ele apenas perguntou uma forma de fazer a chamada.

Comment: Boa tarde Lucius, testei o seu codigo e funcionou. O meu codigo ja apresentava falhas quando o usuario nao informava todos os campos antes, mas nao soube como resolver. Quando vc diz "validar algumas coisas" se refere a nao deixar o cliente enviar o formulario se tiver campos em branco ?

Comment: Na verdade o ideal seria validar tanto no browser (através do JS mesmo) quanto no servidor (através do PHP). No browser: Caso o usuário não preencha algo, você pode mostrar alguma mensagem de erro antes mesmo de enviar o formulário, evitando assim que uma requisição desnecessária seja feita ao servidor. Porém isso por si só não é tão seguro, já que eu posso "burlar" essa validação no meu browser e enviar de qualquer forma. Aí é que entra a validação no servidor. Caso chegue uma requisição sem um dos campos, você pode retornar uma mensagem de erro, que o JS irá pegar e mostrar ao usuário.

Answer (score 0):

**Mudanças no seu PHP**

1. Como o `dataType` do jquery não foi definido trabalhe com números para não dar problemas no retorno. Você poderia trabalhar com echo("sucesso") mas teria que mudar o `dataType` no script e no PHP também haveria uma mudança.

   ```
   if($sql->rowCount()>0){
     echo (1);
   }else{
      echo (2);
   }
   ```
2. Chamar a função conforme explicado na resposta do @Lucius0101

**PHP completo**

```
    <?php
    /* CADASTRO DE CLIENTE */
    function Cadastro() {
      $nome     = $_POST['nome'];
      $dataNasc = explode('-', $_POST['data_nasc']);
      $dataNasc = $dataNasc[2].'-'.$dataNasc[1].'-'.$dataNasc[0];
      $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
      $endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
      $cpf      = $_POST['cpf'];
      $rg       = $_POST['rg'];

       $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=luanaconsolini', 'root', '');

        $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cliente SET
          nome = :nome,
          dataNascimento = :data,
          telefone = :tel,
          endereco = :endereco,
          cpf = :cpf,
          rg = :rg");
        $sql->bindValue(':nome', $nome);
        $sql->bindValue(':data', $dataNasc);
        $sql->bindValue(':tel', $telefone);
        $sql->bindValue(':endereco', $endereco);
        $sql->bindValue(':cpf', $cpf);
        $sql->bindValue(':rg', $rg);
        $sql->execute();
            if($sql->rowCount()>0){
              echo (1);
            }else{
               echo (2);
            }
    }

    if (!empty($_POST)){ 
       Cadastro();
    }
?>
```

**Mudança no seu Script**

```
if (data == 1) {
     alert("Cliente cadastrado com sucesso! :)");
} else if (data == 2){
     alert("Não foi possível realizar o cadastro :( verifique todos os campos ou contate o suporte técnico.");
}
```

**SCRIPT completo**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('form[name="cad-form"]').submit(function(){
      var dados = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
          url: 'cadastro2.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: dados,
          success:function(data){
            if (data == 1) {
              alert("Cliente cadastrado com sucesso! :)");
            } else if (data == 2){
              alert("Não foi possível realizar o cadastro :( verifique todos os campos ou contate o suporte técnico.");
            }
          }
        })
      return false;
    })

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" id="cad-form" name="cad-form" action="">
    <div class="form-group cad-container">
    <label>Qual o nome completo?</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="nome" placeholder="Nome e sobrenome">
    <label>E a data de nascimento?</label>
    <input type="date" inputmode="numeric" name="data_nasc" class="form-control um" id="cad-dat-nasc" placeholder="Data Nascimento">
    <label>Qual o telefone? </label>
    <input inputmode="numeric" name="telefone" class="form-control um" id="cad-tel"placeholder="Ex: (99) 9 9999-9999">
    <label>Onde mora? </label>
    <input class="form-control" name="endereco" placeholder="Rua, numero, bairro e cidade">
    <label>Qual o CPF?</label>
    <input inputmode="numeric" name="cpf" class="form-control um" id="cad-cpf" maxlength="14" placeholder="Ex: 999.999.999-99">
    <label>E o RG?</label>
    <input inputmode="numeric" name="rg" class="form-control um" id="cad-rg"placeholder="Ex: 99.999999-9">
    </div>
    <!--o cad-btn deve estar dentro do formulario-->
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="volta-btn">Voltar</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="cad-btn">Submeter</button>
    </div>
</form>
```